# Prisma model Generation -

Tags: next.js, prisma

Sorry in advance if question is basic, I am beginner.

Is there a way in the schema.prisma definition to enforce a a column to be the result of an operation on several others column ?

e.g. column 1 = Sum ( column 2 + column 3) ?

All that in the same table.
So that if column 3 is modified, column 1 will automatically be updated as well.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While [generated columns](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/ddl-generated-columns.html) aren't natively supported in Prisma, you could use a Postgres trigger to achieve the same behavior.

Here's a step-by-step example of how to create a database table with a "generated" column value when using Prisma.

#### 1. Create the Prisma schema with the optional generated column

This should be self evident. Dummy example:

```
model Foo {
  id        Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
  col1 Int
  col2 Int
  colSum Int?  // colSum = col1 + col2
}
```

#### 2. Write the Trigger

The trigger will update the value of `colSum` field any time there is a create or update operation on the `Foo` Table. This is what it looks like

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION trigger_col_update()
RETURNS TRIGGER
AS $$
BEGIN
  NEW."colSum" := NEW."col1" + NEW."col2";

RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER set_col_trigger
    BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON "Foo"
                         FOR EACH ROW
                         EXECUTE PROCEDURE trigger_col_update();
```

You could manually invoke these SQL commands for your database, but I would recommend storing them in your migration history, as shown in step 3.

#### 3. (Optional) Add trigger to your migration history

Create a new migration file for model `Foo` but do not apply the migration, as you will be making some changes to it manually. You can do this with the `--create-only` flag.

```sh
npx prisma migrate dev --create-only
```

Go to the `migration.sql` file of the generated migration and at the end, paste the SQL provided in step 2.

Apply the migration

```sh
npx prisma migrate dev
```

Now any time you make changes to `col1` or `col2`, it should automatically be reflected in `colSum`.

#### Alternative: Prisma Middleware

The solution with triggers performs the operations in the database server. You could also do these updates in the application layer with [Prisma Middleware](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/middleware). Just perform this same update manually before the query is invoked in Prisma.

However, there are a lot of conditions to check and doing it in the application layer has an unnecessary performance impact. I would not recommend this for the simple use case you mentioned.